# Is the Disk Image Installation Efficient Enough?

Tags: dual-boot, performance, windows-xp, disk-usage

I was just wondering, is it efficient to have the entire Ubuntu file system on a Windows file.

Currently I am using the option to directly boot from Ubuntu, as opposed to running it as an application in Windows. Even so, I notice a slow boot and sluggish performance.

Just to add, I am running a Dual Core, 1 GB RAM machine. Could the performance be slow due to low configuration of the machine.

Comment: Re. your question, it's hard to say but if you've taken the trouble to have a proper dual boot set up, I'd suggest staying with it. I don't see how Wubi would improve the performance, other things being the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's not efficient as the intallation still uses a single windows file to store all the stuffs, which surely is not efficient.